# How can I have different footnotes separators in one Word document?

Tags: microsoft-word, footnote

How can I insert two different types of footnote separators in one Word document?

For example, on one page I'd like the separator to be on the left, and on another page I'd like to have it on the right. This shouldn't depend on whether the pages are odd or even; it should work with arbitrary pages.

I'm dealing with two footnotes in one document. Every time I try to change the footnote separator for one of them (e.g., to right justify it), the other one changes to the same thing.

Comment: Which rule(s) decide where the separator should be? E.g. Left on odd pages, right on even pages? This can be solved with a field (I will update my answer as soon as I have this information.

Or do you need two footnote areas per page?

Comment: no, i mean that one footnote separator in the left and one in the right in another page . for example one in the page 2 and another in page 10.

Comment: Which Word version are you using? E.g. 2000, 2003, 2007 or 2010.

Comment: I USE WORD    2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s a klutzy solution: 
***Delete*** the footnote separator:

[image]

Insert the kind of separator you want before each footnote:

[image]

And there you go:

[image]

[image]

I call this “klutzy” because you will need to take a extra step every time you insert a footnote, you will need to worry about what happens when the insertion or deletion of body text moves the footnotes between pages, and you will need to deal with having two footnotes on one page. 
But I guess you would have to do something like that for any solution, right?

Comment: I’m glad I could help you.  By the way, welcome to Super User.  For your information, it’s conventional to accept and/or upvote answers that you like, or think are good or helpful –– click on the checkmark and/or the up arrow (see [the **How do I ask questions here?** section](http://superuser.com/faq#howtoask) of the FAQ).

Answer (score 1):

The layout and properties of the foot note separator are a document-wide setting. It does not depend on the chapter, section, even/odd page etc.

There are two remedies:

1. Choose different Word documents (files) for each separator type
   -or-
2. Use fields to create a mock-up version of the line: Delete the line, insert a field as [described by Microsoft](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/examples-of-if-fields-HP005187676.aspx). You didn't specify where you want which type, so I cannot help yet with formulating the condition in the IF field, but the values should be something like "---       " and "        ---". Of course you would use more spaces and a hyphen that doesn't leave gaps when repeated. Use Insert -> Symbol or the Windows Charmap program to find candidates.

Comment: i am not familiar with field. where can i use that?

Comment: Before I explain this in detail (I would!), I need to know whether it's actually what you need. Please see my comment above.

Comment: i mean that one footnote separator in the left side of page and other in right side of the page. for example one footnote in right in page 5 and other in the left in page 6.

Answer (score 1):

yes, it's really important when you want to refer to different sources from Latin languages or right to left languages like  Arabic or Persian. if the footnote starts with Latin the footnote separator  should be in the left and if it starts with Arabic it should be in the right. 
with regards,
Ali Tofiq

Comment: yes, that's true i wanted to use it for Persian and English language.